# Why did Charlie say "Helpful shame spiral" in this funny scene?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, bumblebee-2018

In *Bumblebee* (2018), while Charlie was at her job, Bumblebee accidently vandalized her 
furniture in the house. Memo called Charlie, and Charlie confronts Bumblebee in the hall room:

> Charlie: What were you thinking? What... I told you to hide in the garage!
>
> (Bumblebee transform into a car)
>
> Charlie: Great. **Helpful shame spiral**, Bee.

Why did Charlie say, "Helpful shame spiral" in this funny scene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She's being sarcastic. His decision to turn into a car is clearly **not helpful** in the situation and nor are his self-pitying actions and feelings (a "[shame spiral](https://happiful.com/whats-a-shame-spiral/)") after having trashed the place.

Stripped of the sarcastic tone, it becomes

> **Charlie:** *I'm unhappy. The fact that you've decided to feel sorry for yourself and turn into a car is obviously not a helpful attitude in this situation, Bumblebee.*